# Pausing game with State machine and handling jumps

Tags: unity, state

I am adding pause functionality to my upcoming racing game.The players can jump in it.

Time.timeScale = 0 is obvious solution to pause game.I am avoiding this solution as users can do in app purchases in pause menu and with timeScale to 0 its somehow preventing them.

So to overcome that problem I have added state machine pattern to start,pause,resume,finish game.

The thing is when I pause game with my state machine pause behaviour it pauses the game properly without any hesitation until the player is Jumping and pause occurs.

When player is jumping everything gets pause perfectly,just player falls to ground.

So to overcome that problem what I tried was if user pauses game and player is on air the isKinematic on player gets set to to true and game gets pause with player halt on air.

The problem with this approach was that when user resume the game ,unexpected jump movement happens, i.e., player does not land on expected position .

Example if player on y = 10 and game gets pause, with Time.timeScale player will always land on Z = 17 ,but with my this second approach player sometimes land on Z = 20 ,Z = 21 Z = 19 etc

so my question is how will I do properly pause game with state machine without causing unexpected jump movement.

Comment: Since isKinematic was false before pause, you do jumping my manual transformation right? If that so, have you considered doing jumping by adding some velocity, and let's gravity do it's job. That way, you can handle pause by simply setting isKinematic to false.

Comment: Hi,I edited my question more...My game is kart racing and players can jump on it, so with velocity approach,player's landing position always gets differ as player is always moving with diffrent speed so to overcome it I am manually changing player's transforms

Comment: If you manually change the players transforms during jumps can't you just record the values when Paused and reset them to the same when Unpaused?

Comment: You should be able to make a in app purchase during a pause using the timescale. You would however lose the ability to run animations during the pause.

Comment: @JeremiahLeslie with that approach end of Jump's Z position of character is not expected, its random

Comment: Make sure you are record all of the values needed. Logically if you freeze and object then resume it and paste back in all the values it should resume the exact same way it was headed before the pause. I'd make sure your grabbing rigidbody.velocity as well and setting it back on Resume.

Comment: Couldn't you deactivate the physics engine while paused? that would cause all objects to remain at their current positions, but would allow for animations to still play otherwise. Is there a reason why this approach hasn't been tried?